# Configuring Kamailio for RTP Proxying

Tags: kamailio

Would I need to install RTPProxy and RTPEngine for multiple users to send audio to one another? I'm not sure if RTPProxy and RTPEngine are two different modules that does the samething.

Answer (score 2):

`RTPProxy/RTPEngine` are just the same thing. They are used to proxy media mainly for relaying purposes, however `RTPEngine` is an updated `RTPProxy` and you can do much more than just relaying media streams like crypto, capturing `pcaps` and also recording mp3/wav files.

- `RTPProxy` http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.0.x/modules/rtpproxy.html
- `RTPEngine`
  http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.0.x/modules/rtpengine.html

**The better approach as I suggest, is to use RTPEngine**.